# Convert object to associative array returns null value

Tags: php, magento

I am calling a magento soap v2 api and in return geting a respone with an object which I am trying to convert in associative array. But when I am trying to do that with json encode /decode method it is returning an null array.

```
$result = Magento::call()->catalogProductList();
$array = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

1)The object is not empty.
2) Type casting is not an option for me because I am trying to avoid prepending *.

**UPDATE**

this the result value which I am trying to encode.

```
    Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection Object
    (
        [collection:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject Object
                    (
                        [data:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [product_id] => 9
                                [sku] => Tilapia
                                [name] => Tilapia
                                [set] => 4
                                [type] => simple
                                [category_ids] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 2
                                        [1] => 4
                                    )

                                [website_ids] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject Object
                    (
                        [data:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [product_id] => 10
                                [sku] => Deshi Rui
                                [name] => Deshi Rui
                                [set] => 4
                                [type] => simple
                                [category_ids] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 2
                                        [1] => 4
                                    )

                                [website_ids] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

...
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

output of var_export($result)

```
Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection::__set_state(array(
   'collection' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      array (
        'product_id' => '9',
        'sku' => 'Tilapia',
        'name' => 'Tilapia',
        'set' => '4',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'category_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '2',
          1 => '4',
        ),
        'website_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '1',
        ),
      ),
    )),
    1 => 
    Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      array (
        'product_id' => '10',
        'sku' => 'Deshi Rui',
        'name' => 'Deshi Rui',
        'set' => '4',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'category_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '2',
          1 => '4',
        ),
        'website_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '1',
        ),
      ),
    )),

   'count' => 2,
))
```

Comment: What does `json_last_error_msg()` return after your json_encode & json_decode calls?

Comment: thats is strange, what about `json_last_error()` does that return anything useful?

If you get NULL value it is very likely that you hit the recursion limit...

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: var_dump($result) outputs all result as objects.

Comment: Can you post the full result of `var_export($result)` please ?

Comment: @BenoitEsnard added var_export($result) to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` converted your object accordingly to its properties' visibilities.

Since `Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection`'s `$collection` is a protected property, its value isn't read by `json_encode`.

I have two solutions for this problem, one of them requires the modification of Magento's source code, so I would not recommand it, since it could create bugs, or break each time you update your CMS.

---

The first solution uses [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/book.reflection.php), so you will need PHP 5, which shouldn't be a problem since [Magento needs PHP 5.4](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements).

The following function loops through a `\Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection` object to read all properties, and returns an array.

```
function magentoObjectCollectionToArray(\Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection $object)
{
    // The basic structure of your array.
    $array = array(
        'collection' => array()
    );

    // Since $collection is a protected property, we need to reflect it to read the value.
    $collection_reflection = new \ReflectionProperty('\Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection', 'collection');
    // This method allows you to read protected and private properties for the current ReflectionProperty object.
    $collection_reflection->setAccessible(true);

    // Now we need to loop through all objects...
    foreach ($collection_reflection->getValue($object) as $property => $value)
    {
        // Two cases : either a \Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject object, or the $count property.
        if ($value instanceof \Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject)
        {
            // Same here, since $data is also a protected property, we need to reflect it.
            $data_reflection = new \ReflectionProperty('\Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject', 'data');
            $data_reflection->setAccessible(true);

            $array['collection'][$property] = array(
                'data' => $data_reflection->getValue($value)
            );
        }
        else
        {
            // We don't forget the $count property.
            $array['collection'][$property] = $value;
        }
    }

    // And you have your array without using JSON.
    return $array;
}
```

Links to the PHP documentation:

- [`ReflectionProperty::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionproperty.construct.php)
- [`ReflectionProperty::setAccessible`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php)
- [`ReflectionProperty::getValue`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php)

---

The second solution uses [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/class.jsonserializable.php), so you will need PHP 5.4, which shouldn't be a problem neither.

Once the [`jsonSerialize`](http://php.net/manual/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method is implemented on a class which implements JsonSerializable, `json_encode` will encode the return value of `jsonSerialize`.

So, you could modify Magento's core, and make both `\Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObjectCollection` and `\Tinyrocket\Magento\Objects\MagentoObject` classes to implement `\JsonSerializable`, and adding this `JsonSerialize` method to their source code:

```
class XXX implements \JsonSerializable
{
    public function JsonSerialize()
    {
        // Returns all variables. Since we're in the object context, we've access to all of them.
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Then you get your array by calling `json_encode()` / `json_decode()` as you did:

```
json_decode(json_encode($result), true)
```

While this solution may help to solve your problem, I would not recommand it since it requires modifications to Magento's core, which could break other modules and not working anymore after updating.
You should instead create your own plugin and use the first solution, which is the best way to go.

---

Both solutions return this array:

```
array (
  'collection' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'data' => 
      array (
        'product_id' => '9',
        'sku' => 'Tilapia',
        'name' => 'Tilapia',
        'set' => '4',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'category_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '2',
          1 => '4',
        ),
        'website_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '1',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'data' => 
      array (
        'product_id' => '10',
        'sku' => 'Deshi Rui',
        'name' => 'Deshi Rui',
        'set' => '4',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'category_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '2',
          1 => '4',
        ),
        'website_ids' => 
        array (
          0 => '1',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'count' => 2,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Although I couldn't agree less with the fact that your answer is the best and correct one in the question context, I couldn't stop thinking that the real problem comes from the way the web service is returning data and not the way the OP is trying to parse the data. Looks like this module is doing something like `return Mage::getModel('handle/to_module')->getCollection();` when it should actually  `return Mage::getModel('handle/to_module')->getCollection()->toArray();` !

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the $result object is not null, can you try

$array = json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', json_encode($result)), true );

Comment: when you var_dump($result), you are getting the object?

Comment: Oh , then the $result object contains some special characters which are not being possible to json_encode. If it is a small object, please paste the $result value

Comment: @Alvi_1987 First links on a google search on why `json_encode` would return an empty array all points to UTF8 encoding problems. `json_encode` is indeed expecting string to be UTF8 encoded. (as per manuel : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). But I cannot see why a result coming from Magento wouldn't be UTF8. Maybe your soap request is not in UTF8 ?

Comment: @ManafPM added $reslt value to the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

We can tour the object with a for loop .. in , and create our associative array with data. An example:

```
class exampleClass
{
    public $var = 'default value';

    public function showVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$a = new exampleClass();
$array = json_decode(json_encode($a), true);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: You literally gave the same solution that @Alvi_1987 already tried. His issue is that passing the `$result` object through JSON returned an empty array.